# AWS Glue Dynamic Frame Update Column and Crawler Schema Match

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I was reading through the AWS Glue documentation and playing around with the service but I am not able to figure out these 2 things:

1. Can I update all columns to the same value using dynamic frame (similar to UPDATE ALL SQL query) or is there a way to do it is through Spark SQL?
2. I have a Crawler that has created a data catalog from my source database in a new database. Is there a way for me to flag on AWS Glue if the source database schema has changed from the time I created the data catalog to when I schedule the job run?

Apologies if my questions seem silly. Thanks a ton for the help :)

Comment: Can you clarify your first question?

Comment: Edited my post. I'm basically curious if we can use AWS glue spark wrapper to execute update SQL statements. :)

Comment: What is the source database and where do you want to update all columns to the same value (source or destination)?

Comment: @bdcloud I want to update all the columns in the source database itself.

Answer (score 1):

1. Not sure how to do this directly using dynamic frames of spark SQL, but it can be done using DataFrames.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

# Load dynamic_frame with data.
dynamic_frame = ...

# Convert to Spark DataFrame
df = dynamic_frame.toDF()

# Loop over columns and set records to a constant value, e.g. 999
for column in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumn(column, lit(999))

# Convert back to DynamicFrame
dynamic_frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "dynamic_frame")
```

2. I'm not aware of an option to flag a changed database schema. But you could create something like this yourself: make a simple script that reads a flag you set somewhere and let this script trigger the crawler. This can be done with boto3 in Python or with the aws cli for example.